# Merged cells when exporting to Excel (ReportBuilder)

Tags: delphi, export-to-excel, delphi-xe3, reportbuilder

I am using Report Builder (15.03) with Delphi XE3 for reports generating purposes.

In the Print Preview screen there is a printer icon on the left top corner. Clicking on it opens the Print dialog where there is "Print to File" option. Selecting the "XLS Report File" type there will exports the report to Excel file. However if the column width is big enough it will export it into merged cells in Excel. You can see on my second screenshot cells from E till F are merged.

I started face this issue only after we upgraded our Report Builder to XE3 version. In Delphi 5 version there was no problem.

Has anyone faced the same issue before? Is there any way to avoid the cells merging in this case?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Regards,

Alexey

Comment: Have you asked Digital Metaphors support? That should be your first source for support for their components.

Comment: @Ken White, yes I did. We bought their components few years ago but the support subscription licence has already expired.

Comment: Sharing the answer here that I found by myself. Just in case someone will need it in the future. The cells merging can be switched of by setting ppReport1.XLSSettings.MergeAdjacentCells := False; (by default it is True).

Comment: If you want to share a solution, do so properly by writing an answer in the space below. Answering your own question is acceptable here; see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for details. Editing the answer into the question is inappropriate, as is adding [SOLVED] to the title. (I've rolled back your edit that did both.)

Comment: @KenWhite, Thanks. I did not know that. This is my first time.

Comment: You're welcome. :-) Everyone was new here at one time. No harm done.

Answer (score 0):

The cells merging can be switched of by setting:

```
ppReport1.XLSSettings.MergeAdjacentCells := False;
```

(by default it is True).